# Track touches across ViewControllers

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I am trying to track touches across ViewControllers / Transitions.
To be more precise:
I have `viewControllerA` and `viewControllerB`

`viewControllerA` has a Button with a Microphone on it.
Once you tap it, `viewControllerB` comes up. It has let's say a level meter for the microphone input and also a record button. Once you tap and hold it, you can see the input of the microphone.
So far, so easy.

What I would like to do is, tap and hold the microphone button in `viewControllerA`, which should cause `viewControllerB` to come up, and immediatly showing the input levels, as long as I still have my finger on the screen.

How would I go about that?
Please note, that the actual implementation and recording logic is a bit more complex than described here. Therefor I wouldn't like a solution that only uses one ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

How do you present **viewControllerB**? Maybe try to make **viewControllerB** as childViewController of **viewControllerA**
You will be able to track touches in two controllers and comunicate to parent by delegate for example.